# I would like to create a new forge app by code. Is there any api available?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

It is the UI at [https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps/->Create](https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps/-%3ECreate) App I would like to bypass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this can not be achieved by API currently, need to operate from UI.